# Virus Scan in Nodejs Before Upload to the server

Tags: node.js

When uploading a malicious file in this time needs scanning and remove that file. any special package is there in NPM? Can you help me with this anyone thanks advance?

Comment: Have you looked at https://kainikhil.medium.com/nodejs-file-upload-and-virus-scan-9f23691394f3?

Comment: Have to upgrade the medium to read this